# ANR on every launch after updating to Google Play Services 9.0.1 Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I had my app published for a very long time. Now I was working on the update and when i update my google play services to 9.0.1, my app keep going to ANR state on every launch showing me a complete blank screen.
All i have done is added new dependencies required for update.
here is the `build.gradle` file of app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "5.2"
    ndk {
        moduleName "Constants"
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/libs"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:2.5.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is the application level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the log is showing no error. Can anyone help me with this and tell what is the problem here?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turn out I had an error in my native code which was causing that ANR state.

Answer (score 0):

Since the log is showing no error, ANR could be caused by long operations in the main thread or also called UI thread. Your app then can't process other user interactions since the UI thread is blocked. Solution you can do is to do heavy operations in a worker thread to free-up the UI thread.

As mentioned in [Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads):

> When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.

Also,

> It's vital to the responsiveness of your application's UI that you do not block the UI thread. If you have operations to perform that are not instantaneous, you should make sure to do them in separate threads ("background" or "worker" threads).

Several ways to access the UI thread from other threads which Android already offers to fix ANR issues are further discussed in the documentation.

Comment: Well it turn out to be an error in my NDK code .. It wasnt showing me on my LogCat but after debugging i found it. But still thanks for your detailed answer.